# TypeScript Como obtengo la cantidad de datos que tengo en un JSON

Tags: html, angular, typescript

primero que nada disculpen si no se entiende muy bie mi pregunta, soy nuevo en esto y quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar quiero obtener la cantidad de elementos que tengo en mi data.json y mostrarlos en un label en html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi html y este es mi data.json

```
{
"knowledges": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "WHAT IS FOOD WASTE?",
    "urlToImage": "https://tgtg-mkt-cms-prod.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2659/WvU19FlXwjibPBY0",
    "summary": "Whilst plenty of research has been conducted on the issue, there still isn't a clear and consistent approach when it comes to defining or quantifying food waste. So, here are some different interpretations as well as our own take on this.",
    "content": "DEFINITIONS\nFood loss: a decrease in quantity and quality of agricultural, forestry and fishery products intended for human consumption that are ultimately not eaten by people. Food losses occur along the supply chain from production, to harvest, post-harvest handling, to storage and processing, and during transportation (FAO, 2017)\nFood waste: food appropriate for human consumption being discarded or left to spoil at consumer level â€“ regardless of the cause (HLPE, 2014)\nFood loss and waste: a decrease at all stages of the food system from production to consumption, in mass and/or quality, of food that was originally intended for human consumption, regardless of the cause (FAO, 2017)\nThere is simply no right or wrong way to define it, and so to keep things simple we decided to call the entire issue from farm to fork: Food Waste"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "WHERE IS FOOD WASTED?",
    "urlToImage": "https://tgtg-mkt-cms-prod.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2660/RTXBvKN9aZIY99Fb",
    "summary": "Humanity is dependent on food to survive. Yet, in every corner of the world food is wasted for different reasons and in various, different circumstances.",
    "content": "DEVELOPING NATIONS\nDeveloping nations experience greater unintended post-harvest losses at the start of the value chain because of inadequate technology, transportation infrastructure, storage and cooling facilities, and more extreme weather conditions.\n\nThe developing world accounts for 44% of food waste and loss in the world (Lipinski et al., 2013)\nIn developing countries 40% of losses occur during harvest and processing level (FAO 2016)\nInterventions within these systems focus on training and upgrading technical capacity to reduce losses, increase efficiency and reduce labour intensity of the technologies employed (Parfitt et al., 2010)."
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "WHY IS FOOD WASTED?\n",
    "urlToImage": "https://tgtg-mkt-cms-prod.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2978/flsXOhXQTgZLtzfK",
    "summary": "Nowadays, food is transported over long distances across continents. This means that end consumers are becoming increasingly disconnected from the source and the supply chain becomes longer and more fragmented. Food waste is in may ways a systemic issue rather than the fault of just one entity. To solve it, different stakeholders will need to coordinate and collaborate in harmony.",
    "content": "FOOD WASTE OCCURS AT ALL STAGES FROM FARM TO FORK\nAs food travels all the way from the producer to the consumer, it moves through various stages. There are many different reasons why food is either lost or wasted within these different steps, but these can be summarised to (BCG, 2018):\n\nLack of awareness of the problem and the solutions at hand\nInadequate supply chain infrastructure\nSupply chain inefficiency\nWeak collaboration across the value chain\nInsufficient regulations."
  }
]}
```

El id esta definido en los models en un archio knowledges.ts, en si explicando un poco mejor en mi pestaña home quiero que aparezca esa cantidad de elementos registrados, pero el home no tiene ningun dato definido, entiendo que debo de obtenerlo de mi knowledges pero no tengo idea de como, no se si me podrian ayudar porfavor

Comment: Etiquetas de html y TS, pero no la de Angular... por favor usa bien las etiquetas, son importantes. Y me temo que aquí no hacemos tutoriales, hablando de ellos... te recomiendo ver uno (o más de uno), e intentar hacerlo tú mismo. Actualmente tu código no hace absolutamente nada para leer el archivo, y nosotros no vamos a hacerlo por ti, debes hacerlo tú mismo y si tienes un **problema concreto** te podemos ayudar con él. Si estás aprendiendo, la única manera de aprender es practicar.

Answer (score 0):

podemos interpolar el resultado del array directamente en el HTML:
antes que nada debes asignar el json a una variable en el archivo ts (home.component.ts):

```
let jsonAux = {
   knowledges: [
     { "id":1 },
     { "id":2 }
   ]
}
```

Una vez tenemos el json asignado en una variable, podemos interpolar el numero de items en el campo "knowledges", para eso en el archivo "home.component.html" debemos poner lo siguiente:

```
{{jsonAux.knowledges.lenght}}
```

Con esto puedes mostrar el numero de items de un array en la parte de HTML.